# I attempted to read from an Intel 87C54 microcontroller and it came up all FF's. Any way to read from this?

Tags: firmware, hardware, dumping

I'm using the popular TL866II Plus programmer to read from the chip. I see in the [datasheet](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/980707/Intel/87C54/1) that it has lock bits which can disable the verify (read) function, but I'm not sure if that causes an attempted verify to yield all FF's, or if it would give an error of some kind.

In the situation where the lock bits are in fact set, is there any known way to bypass them and dump the firmware from the chip? Keep in mind, this chip came from a very rare board, and that chip is the only copy I have of the program, so I don't want to risk erasing it.

Comment: Did you remove the chip from the board or trying to dump it in-circuit?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky I removed it from a socket on the board. Also, it might be worth mentioning that the same result occurs if I attempt the dump without actually having the chip connected to the programmer.